# EF not saving virtual properties when editing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a model `Team` which looks like this:

```
public class Team
{
    [Key]
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
}
```

I have a method to `Edit` it:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(Team team)
{
    using (var db = new DbConnection())
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(team).State = EntityState.Modified;

            db.Groups.Attach(team.Group);

            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        return PartialView(team);
    }
}
```

However it is not saving the change to the `Group` column. Meanwhile `Create` method does work although I see no difference between them:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Team team)
{
    using (var db = new DbConnection())
    {                
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Groups.Attach(team.Group);

            db.Teams.Add(team);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return PartialView(team);
    }
}
```

The values for the `Group` come the same in both methods. I bring the values to the form like this (again, same thing for both):

```
ViewBag.Groups = db.Groups.ToList().Select(g => new SelectListItem()
{
    Text = g.Code,
    Value = g.GroupId.ToString(),
    Selected = false
}).ToList();
```

and use them like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Group.GroupId, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Groups)
```

**Can someone please explain what the difference between the two methods** is (in terms of one saving `Group` and other - not)?

P.S. Using both the latest MVC and EF.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is a must (?) (at least I couldn't find anything better) to add a field matching the type of the `Group` in order to be able to easily save. No need to attach anything this way. Now my model looks like:

```
public class Team
{
    [Key]
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public int? GroupId { get; set; }
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
}
```

and my `Save` and `Create` methods got this line:

```
db.Groups.Attach(team.Group);
```

removed.